# Do Android apps need to add any dependency in order to support CUPS (Common Unix Printing System/Server)

Tags: android, printing, cups, android-print-framework, android-print-manager

I have an Android app having support for PDF printing. I have used PrintManager class to implement printing behaviour for the app and for Chromebook we were using Cloud Print. Now as google have deprecated cloud print in January of 2021 and is no longer supported, and have mentioned "Printing (CUPS - Common Unix Printing System/Server) for Chrome OS devices". I tried looking for any CUPS library but could not find anything related to CUPS library for Android.
Does anyone know about any CUPS library for Android which might be required to integrate in the app to support CUPS or it is something which will be automatically taken care by Android printing service and we do not need to make any change?